# Do Func and Action delegates become null if the source object becomes dereferenced?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, scope, delegates

Define these variables in Class A:

```
public int CubeAnInt32(int n)
{
    return n * n * n;
}
```

And these variables in Class B:

```
public void CubeAnInt32WithDelegate(int k, Func<int, int> delg)
{
    return delg(k);
}
```

And an overall scope:

```
/// Note that this is outside the scope of SomeArbitraryCallback()
Func<int, int> cube = default;

public void SomeArbitraryCallback()
{
    var refWithinScope = new ClassA();
    cube = refWithinScope.CubeAnInt32;
    return;
}

public void AnotherCallbackPerformedAfter()
{
    var cubeDependent = new ClassB();

    /// Does this throw a NullReferenceException because of 'cube'?
    /// Has the delegate assigned to 'cube' been dereferenced?
    var result = cubeDependent.CubeAnInt32WithDelegate(0, cube);
    return result;
}
```

Will a delegate whose object has been "de-scoped" (i.e. cube) be dereferenced? Or will this delegate reference the assigned object and prevent it from being GC'd?

Comment: why not just try it out? Debug and see what happens.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain this is typically the best way to figure something out. But I wanted to be absolutely sure there were no edge cases to be aware of. I don’t know the internal implementation, so an interaction that works in unit-testing may not actually work in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/ - "A delegate is a type that represents **references** to methods" (emphasis is mine).

So as long as your delegate (`cube`) remains in scope, a reference is held and `refWithinScope` (of type `ClassA`) will not be collected.

Whether you *want* to have this sort of design is a different discussion: looks like a good candidate for introducing subtle, unintended bugs in future re-factors.

Answer (score -1):

A delegate - concerning referencing `null`- is in no way different from any other type. So if the variable is `null` and you try to invoke it, you surely get a `NullReferenceException`.

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs>  MyEvent;

private void RaiseEvent()
{
    MyEvent.Invoke(this, myEventArgs);
}
```

So of course you need to assign somethig to your delegate, otherwise it's just `null`.

The same applies to a property. Unless you don't assignt any value to it, it will allways have its default-value, which is `null` for reference-types:

```
public string MyString { get; set; }
private void DoSomething()
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyString.Length); // crash here
}
```

Coming back to your code, `Func<int, int> cube = default;` will just assign `null` to `cube`. So when you call `CubeAnInt32WithDelegate` *before* having assigned something to the delegate, e.g. by calling `SomeArbitraryCallback`, you will get an NRE.